# Workaround for open lualatex bug in \scantokens?

Tags: luatex, verbatim, expansion

As package author I am in need of writing a manual with lots of examples.

Now I started to make heavy use of `lualatex` in order to speed up operations which take a long time in TeX (of my package, not the manual) -- and I stumbled about an open ticket (bug?) of lualatex which blocks me when I attempt to activate my code changes in the manual.

Background:

An example in my manual should be something like

```
\begin{codeexample}[]
<code here>
\end{codeexample}
```

and should result in (1) the listing in some verbatim output and (2) the result of executing `<code>`. I want to type the listing once (and once only).

This is a good use-case for `\scantokens` : I collect the tokens with category code 12 (other) in order to show the verbatim output as code listing. This listing will include syntax highlighting and automatic cross references. Afterwards I use `\scantokens` in order to reset the category codes to their initial meaning such that I can execute the code (to show the outcome).

This last invocation of `\scantokens` works flawlessly in pdftex. It does not work at all in lualatex.

The issue is known, see http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=733 and [\scantokens in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65151/scantokens-in-luatex) .

While I could write a lua version of my package and translate the manual with the pdftex version, I would rather see the effects and document special cases. Eventually, the lua version might offer unique capabilities. Consequently, I do not want to wait until someone else fixes that open ticket - and I am searching for workarounds.

Does anyone know a workaround?

The problem as such can be formulated very simple as pointed out in the linked tex.se question. I would formulate it as

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}

Here should come text: \scantokens{^^JNamely this text}

\end{document}
```

pdftex results in

[image]

whereas luatex results in

[image]

which is the same as in the linked question.

But I need the newlines in my use case.

This here is a reduced (I suppose minimal) example of my use-case in which I collect a listing verbatim and reassign catcodes afterwards in order to execute the listing. This "execute the listing" needs the newlines, otherwise it will fail to work. And: yes, I do not typeset the listing here (it is a minimal example).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\makeatletter
% Define \find@example such that it doesn't destroy catcodes:
\begingroup
\catcode`|=0
\catcode`[= 1
\catcode`]=2
\catcode`\{=12
\catcode `\}=12
\catcode`\\=12 |gdef|find@example#1\end{codeexample}[|endofcodeexample[#1]]
|endgroup

\def\OLDNEWLINE{^^J}%
%% ATTEMPT (1*):
%% This here result in output of the first minimal. But it breaks the
%% second one.
%%\def\OLDNEWLINE{}%

% define \returntospace.
%
% It should define NEWLINE as {}, spaces and tabs as \space.
\begingroup
\catcode`\^=7
\catcode`\^^M=13
\catcode`\^^I=13
\catcode`\ =13%
\gdef\returntospace{\catcode`\ =13\def {\space}\catcode`\^^I=13\def^^I{\space}\catcode`\^^M=13\def^^M{\OLDNEWLINE}}%
% 
% ATTEMPT (2*):
%\gdef\returntospace{\catcode`\ =13\def {\space}\catcode`\^^I=13\def^^I{\space}\catcode`\^^M=13}%
\endgroup

\def\codeexample[#1]{%
    \parindent0pt
    \begingroup%
    \par%
    \medskip%
    \let\do\@makeother%
    \dospecials%
    \obeylines%
    \@vobeyspaces%
    \catcode`\^^M=13 %
    \find@example}
\def\endofcodeexample#1{%
    \endgroup%
    {%
      \returntospace%
      \xdef\code@temp{#1}% removes returns and comments
    }%
    %
    % ATTEMPT (2*): This here fixes the first minimal example together with (2*):
    %\catcode`\^^M=9 % 9 == ignore
    \expandafter\scantokens\expandafter{\code@temp}%
  \end{codeexample}
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

This should result in the picture:
\begin{codeexample}[]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red,->] (0,0) -- (1,1);

    \draw[green] (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{codeexample}

This should result in the table: 
\begin{codeexample}[]
\pgfplotstabletypeset{%
A B
2 3
4 5
}
\end{codeexample}
\end{document}
```

pdftex generates the expected outcome which is

[image]

whereas the luatex output is

[image]

I already tried a couple of things as outlined in the code. I already had the idea to use

```
\scantokens{\def\CONTENT{<sequence of 'other' catcodes}}
```

and use a "search-and-replace" routine on `\CONTENT` to replace every occurence of newlines with - well, I did not know with what. And simple search-and-replace routines will fail with curly braces inside of this macro.

I have used Tex live 2013 (2014 does not fit on my hard drive currently). The lua ticket is in state "new" so I do not expect useful updates.

So: does anyone have an idea how I could adopt this codeexample code in order to (a) collect the listing of both examples and (b) execute both listings successfully *without* modifying the listings as such?

Comment: Can't you write the code like showexpl does it to an external file? Or change the catcodetable in luatex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the idea with a tmp file would work, right (maybe that should become an answer)! I am unfamiliar with luatex's catcodetables. Can you achieve the desired effect with them? I would like to hear about it (sounds like less overhead)

Comment: I don't have the time to look about the catcode table (just came back and have a lot to do), but imho they should be a better way if you don't need a pdflatex solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the note. I'll do some research next week. Sounds like a better approach, yes. Temp files are always ugly...

Comment: I have managed to experiment a lot: the idea to use something of sorts `\directlua{local var=[==[\code@temp]==]; io.write("processing " .. var .. "-------\noexpand\n"); tex.sprint(0, var)}` is quite good... however, it handles newline characters in a very confusing way. I will file a new question in order to understand that stuff. For now it seems as if writing the code into a tmp file is the best solution. Do you want to add it as answer?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Better than `[==[\code@temp]==]` is to use `"\luaescapestring{\code@temp}"` (perhaps LuaLaTeX renames that primitive).  Also, you might have some luck using `\scantokens` after setting `\newlinechar` to `-1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `\scantokens\expandafter{\code@temp}`, you can pass the string to Lua, let it split the string at new lines, and `tex.print` each line.  Calling `tex.print` only once would result in a single line of input, and no amount of catcode trickery would make TeX behave as if there were multiple lines.

I thus use the following Lua code in the full example below:

```
local s = "\luaescapestring{\code@temp}"
for line in s:gmatch("[^\string\n]+") do
  tex.print(line)
end
```

As it is, the code is not quite a replacement for `\scantokens`.  A more accurate replacement would be the following, which takes care of the value of `\newlinechar`.  If it is negative (well, I should also test for when it is too big) then output the string directly.  Otherwise, set the variable `newline` to the new line character (as a Lua string), possibly with an escaping `%`, then define a pattern which matches any sequence of one or more characters other than a new line (actually I just realize that this will fail when there are two new lines in a row), and print each such sequence through `tex.print`.

```
\long\def\myscantokens#1{\directlua{%
  local s = "\luaescapestring{\detokenize{#1}}"
  if \the\newlinechar < 0 then
    tex.print(s)
  else
    local newline = string.char(\the\newlinechar)
    if not newline:match("\string\%w") then
      newline = "\string\%" .. newline
    end
    local pattern = "[^" .. newline .. "]+"
    for line in s:gmatch(pattern) do
      tex.print(line)
    end
  end}}
```

Anyhow, here I'll use the simpler code since it seems to work for your case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\makeatletter
% Define \find@example such that it doesn't destroy catcodes:
\begingroup
\catcode`|=0
\catcode`[= 1
\catcode`]=2
\catcode`\{=12
\catcode `\}=12
\catcode`\\=12 |gdef|find@example#1\end{codeexample}[|endofcodeexample[#1]]
|endgroup

\def\OLDNEWLINE{^^J}%

% define \returntospace.
%
% It should define NEWLINE as {}, spaces and tabs as \space.
\begingroup
\catcode`\^=7
\catcode`\^^M=13
\catcode`\^^I=13
\catcode`\ =13%
\gdef\returntospace{\catcode`\ =13\def {\space}\catcode`\^^I=13\def^^I{\space}\catcode`\^^M=13\def^^M{\OLDNEWLINE}}%
\endgroup

\def\codeexample[#1]{%
    \parindent0pt
    \begingroup%
    \par%
    \medskip%
    \let\do\@makeother%
    \dospecials%
    \obeylines%
    \@vobeyspaces%
    \catcode`\^^M=13 %
    \find@example}
\def\endofcodeexample#1{%
    \endgroup%
    {%
      \returntospace%
      \xdef\code@temp{#1}% removes returns and comments
    }%
    \directlua
      {%
        local s = "\luaescapestring{\code@temp}"
        for line in s:gmatch("[^\string\n]+") do
          tex.print(line)
        end
      }%
  \end{codeexample}
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

This should result in the picture:
\begin{codeexample}[]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red,->] (0,0) -- (1,1);

    \draw[green] (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{codeexample}

This should result in the table: 
\begin{codeexample}[]
\pgfplotstabletypeset{%
A B
2 3
4 5
}
\end{codeexample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Two comments: In a LaTeX document, one should probably use `"\luatexluaescapestring{\detokenize{#1}}"` rather than `"\luaescapestring{\detokenize{#1}}"`. Second, to avoid having to use this dreadful macro name, you could load the `luacode` package and simply type `\luatring{\detokenize{#1}}`. Note: a side benefit of using `\luastring` is that the double quotes that must surround `\luatexluaescapestring` can also be dispensed with.

Comment: Tricky. Seems as if my approaches in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198674/luatex-and-starting-tex-macros-which-handle-new-line-characters have been the right direction... I should have applied it to the codeexample stuff rather than playing with the minimal example in the linked question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For the record, I've replied to Christian's question there.

Comment: For the records: I have used a slightly modified approach which also keeps empty lines.