# Workaround to make catchbetweenfiletags work with lualatex

Tags: luatex, incompatibility, input, catchfile

I recently discovered that a basic example of the package `catchbetweenfiletags` doesn't work with `lualatex` (while it works with `pdflatex`).

What follows is the MWE. Do you know if there is workaround to make it work with `lualatex`?

File `catch1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\begin{document}
test
\ExecuteMetaData[catch2]{mytag}
\end{document}
```

File `catch2.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%<*mytag>
CATCH2
%</mytag>
\end{document}
```

`$ pdflatex catch1.tex` works as expected.

`$ lualatex catch1.tex` gives this error:

```
Runaway text?
! File ended while scanning text of \CatchFBT@tok.
<inserted text> 
}
l.7 \ExecuteMetaData[catch2]{mytag}

?
```

Versions:

`pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)`

`This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014) (rev 4971)`

`catchfilebetweentags : 2011/02/19 v1.1`

For reference, using the package's command `\CatchFileBetweenTags` fails in the same way. From the comment by @egreg, it also works with `xelatex`.

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be in the fact that LuaTeX uses Unicode for input, because XeLaTeX works without problems.

Comment: Imho it is the same problem than this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65151/scantokens-in-luatex and this http://tug.org/pipermail/lualatex-dev/2011-November/001376.html. The package changes `\endlinechar` and so luatex slides over the end of the file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, confirmed. If I comment the line 80 of `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/catchfilebetweentags/catchfilebetweentags.sty` where it says: "   \endlinechar=`\^^J%" it then works with LuaLaTeX. I don't know if it is a good idea, it seems to work (For what it worths, I tested also for a file with several line breaks and paragraph, both with PDFLaTeX and LuaLaTeX)

Comment: Yes this works, but in my tests it gives different line breaks than with pdflatex (and the `\endlinechar` setting).

Answer (score 7):

Imho it is the same problem than this one: [\scantokens in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65151/scantokens-in-luatex) and this http://tug.org/pipermail/lualatex-dev/2011-November/001376.html. The package changes `\endlinechar` and so luatex slides over the end of the file.

One can avoid the error message by disabling the `\endlinechar` change:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags,ifluatex}
\makeatletter
\def\CatchFBT@sanitize{%
   \@sanitize
   \@makeother\{%
   \@makeother\}%
   \ifluatex\else
   \endlinechar=`\^^J%
   \fi
}% 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
test
\ExecuteMetaData[catch2]{mytag}
\end{document}
```

One can also set `^^J` to be an "end of line char".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags,ifluatex}
\makeatletter
\def\CatchFBT@sanitize{%
   \@sanitize
   \@makeother\{%
   \@makeother\}%
   \endlinechar=`\^^J%
   \ifluatex
   \catcode`\^^J=5
   \fi
}% 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
test
\ExecuteMetaData[catch2]{mytag}

\end{document}
```

But both changes the output compared to pdflatex if the catched file contains empty lines.

Comment: Is it possible to add something between `\ifluatex` and `\else` such that in both cases (pdflatex and lualatex) the output is the same?

Comment: In the first example you can simply remove the `\endlinechar` setting completly. In the second you can remove the `\ifluatex` and the `\fi`. But in both cases you will get different output in pdflatex then with the original settings of the package.

Answer (score 5):

I tried various things to go around the buggy `\scantokens` from LuaTeX. In the end the most robust appears to me (for the time being) to just drop using `\scantokens` in that context and go through a real intermediate file. Here is the code:

```
% \scantokens is buggy in LuaTeX
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65151/scantokens-in-luatex
% http://tug.org/pipermail/lualatex-dev/2011-November/001376.html

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{catch2}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%<*mytag>
CATCH2
SECOND LINE

THIRD LINE AFTER ONE EMPTY LINE


FOURTH LINE AFTER TWO EMPTY LINES
%</mytag>
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

% CIRCUMVENTING LUALATEX BUGGY \scantokens

\makeatletter

\ifluatex 
   \newwrite\CATCHPATCHOUT
\fi

\def\CatchFBT@Fin@l#1[#2]{%
   \begingroup
      \endlinechar\m@ne \makeatletter #2%
      \ifluatex
         \immediate\openout\CATCHPATCHOUT=\jobname.catchpatch
         \immediate\write\CATCHPATCHOUT {\CatchFBT@tok{\the\CatchFBT@tok}}%
         \immediate\closeout\CATCHPATCHOUT
         \@@input \jobname.catchpatch
      \else
      \scantokens\expandafter{%
         \expandafter\CatchFBT@tok\expandafter{\the\CatchFBT@tok}}%
      \fi
      \CatchFBT@IsAToken{#1}
         {\global#1\expandafter{\the\CatchFBT@tok}}
         {\xdef#1{\the\CatchFBT@tok}}%
      \ifx\CatchFBT@tok#1\else\global\CatchFBT@tok{}\fi
   \endgroup
}% \CatchFBT@Final
\makeatother

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\ttfamily


\CatchFileBetweenTags\tmp{catch2}{mytag}

\meaning\tmp

\noindent\ExecuteMetaData [catch2]{mytag}

\end{document}
```

On this example, the following is obtained, be it with pdfTeX or LuaLaTeX:

[image]

Notice that this is the behavior of package `catchfilebetweentags`: if you want to reinstore line breaks you should use the final optional argument to `\CatchFileBetweenTags` to modify `\endlinechar` from its `-1` setting.

Example:

```
\CatchFileBetweenTags\tmp{catch2}{mytag}[\endlinechar=13 ]

\meaning\tmp
```

Again we obtain the same result with both engines:

[image]

Notice that the space before CATCH comes from the end of line of the tag line. This is what the package does (nothing to do with my patch here).